# install bbswitch to disable nvdia graphic card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics

i want to permanently disable nvidia gcard on my laptop. i just finished installation of ubuntu. so please post every step. and there is no option on in BIOS to disable gpu. ubuntu is 14.04. laptop=hp 15 r203tx
gp is 820m

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install proper driver for this adapter and disable it using nvidia-prime. Run in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

reboot and run in terminal

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

log off and log on or reboot.

Your Nvidia GPU will be disabled, but can always be enabled by

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

or using Nvidia X Server Settings program.